# Guard your can with your life!

Tags: game, king-of-the-hill, path-finding

## Lets Play Kick The Can!

### Although Moogie is the current winner, if anyone can take his crown they are encouraged to do so

Kick the can is a children's game. Involving one defender, and multiple attackers. Today it is no longer such a game! Your job is to write a bot that plays it, to win, [king-of-the-hill](/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) style!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kick_the_can

There are some key differences in this game. The first key difference is that the game is multiplayer (5v5). The second key difference is that both sets of bots can kill and eliminate enemy players with both mines and thrown bombs! Bots can not see any mines (regardless of distance) or players at greater than five blocks away!

The map is a maze as follows.

[image: Maze]

This maze is procedurally generated by first creating a maze using a depth first recursive backtracking algorithm. And then placing the shown holes in (as well as make the maze more "imperfect". The maze is 65x65 blocks wide, and zero indexed. Thus the blue flag (can) is at 1,1 and the red flag (can) is at 63,63. Blue team spawns at 2,2 and 3,3 4,4 etc. red team spawns at 62,62 and 61,61, 60,60 etc. The blocks in cyan are bots on the blue team, and the blocks in magenta are red bots. The game is always five versus five. Each bot on the team will use your code (but may store other instance variables (or create local files) to keep track of state and differentiate roles.

---

### Gameplay

Mines can be placed as you can see in gray. And bombs can be thrown a maximum distance of up to four blocks. These travel for up to four blocks through walls and other players killing only the enemies which stand in your way. After each step they have a 40% chance of falling away. So they have 100% chance of 1 range 60% at 2 range 36% at 3 range and 21.6% at three range Placing a mine or throwing a bomb takes one team ammo. This starts at 0 and can be increased by collecting the orange boxes. Note that four (4) of these ammo caches will be conveniently centered. The Bots are lined up in an array of two red and two blue. I.E RRRRRBBBBB. Gaurding the flag is permitted, but beware that being near the flag(i.e less than five blocks) results in slowness, and only allows movent. every three turns. The Arena picks a random starter for each turn. I.E The order can be RBBBBBRRRRR BBBBBRRRRR BBBRRRRRBB etc..

### Objective

Program your five bots (each has the same class file) to successfully navigate the maze and touch the opposing can while being careful not to accidentally knock over ones own can, or step on a mine.

### Programming

The arena and bot entries are currently in Java however a stdin/out wrapper exists for other languages.

The arena code will be made available but here is the relevant details.

#### Bot Class

```
public class YourUniqueBotName extends Bot{
public YourUniqueBotName(int x , int y, int team){
super(x,y,team);
//optional code
}
public Move move(){//todo implement this method 
//it should output  a Move();
//A move has two paramaters
//direction is from 0 - 3 as such
//         3
//       2-I-0
//         1
// a direction of 4 or higher means a no-op (i.e stay still)
//And a MoveType. This movetype can be    
//MoveType.Throw
//MoveType.Mine
//MoveType.Defuse defuse any mine present in the direction given
//MoveType.Move
}
}
```

#### Key Methods Available

Note that using any techniques to modify or access data you should generally not have access to is not permitted and will result in disqualification.

```
Arena.getAmmo()[team];//returns the shared ammo cache of your team

Arena.getMap();//returns an integer[] representing the map. Be careful since all enemies more than 5 blocks away (straight line distance) and all mines are replaced with constant for spaces
//constants for each block type are provided such as Bot.space Bot.wall Bot.mine Bot.redTeam Bot.blueTeam Bot.redFlag Bot.blueFlag

Arena.getAliveBots();//returns the number of bots left

getX();//returns a zero indexed x coordinate you may directly look at (but not change X)

getY();//returns a zero indexed y coordinate (y would work to, but do not change y's value)

//Although some state variables are public please do not cheat by accessing modifying these
```

#### StdIn/Out wrapper Interface Specification

The interface consists of two modes: initialisation and running.

During initialisation mode, a single INIT frame is sent via stdout. This frame's specification is as follows:

```
INIT
{Team Membership Id}
{Game Map}
TINI
```

Where:
{Team Membership Id} is an single character: R or B. B meaning blue team, R meaning red team.

{Game Map} is a series of rows of ascii characters representing one row of the map. The following ascii characters are valid:
    F = blue flag
    G = red flag
    O = open space
    W = wall

The game will then proceed to send game frames over stdout to each bot as so:

```
FRAME
{Ammo}
{Alive Bot Count}
{Bot X},{Bot Y}
{Local Map}
EMARF
```

Where:

{Ammo} is a string of digits, value will be 0 or greater
{Alive Bot Count} is a string of digits, value will be 0 or greater
{Box X} is a string of digits representing the X co-ordinate of the bot on the game map. Value will be 0 <= X < Map Width.
{Box Y} is a string of digits representing the Y co-ordinate of the bot on the game map. Value will be 0 <= Y < Map Height.
{Local Map} is a series of rows of ascii characters representing the whole map surrounding the bot. The following ascii characters are valid:
    F = blue flag
    G = red flag
    O = open space
    W = wall
    R = red team bot
    B = blue team bot
    M = mine
    A = ammo

The Controller expects that your bot will then output (to stdout) a single line response in the format:

```
{Action},{Direction}
```

Where:

{Action} is one of:
    Move 
    Defuse
    Mine
    Throw

{Direction} is a single digit between 0 and 4 inclusive. (see direction information earlier)

NOTE: all strings will be delimited by \n End of Line character.

This will be an elimination tournament. My sample bots will participate as fillers, but I will not award myself the win. In the event of a victory by one of my bots, the title goes to the second place member, and will continue until there is a bot which is not one of mine. Each match consists of 11 rounds of kick the can. If neither team has won a single match by then they both are eliminated. If there is a tie of non-zero score one tie breaker match will be played. If a tie remains both are eliminated. Later rounds may consist of more matches. The seeding of the tournament will be based on the number of upvotes as of 7/31/16 (date subject to change).

Each match lasts 4096 turns. A victory grants one point. A tie or loss grants zero points. Good luck!

Feel free to look at the code or critique it at this GitHub Repo.

https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/BotCTF/blob/master/src/botctf/Arena.java

---

Note that I do not have interpreters for too many languages on my computer, and I may need volunteers to run the simulation on their computer. Or I can download the language interpreter. Please ensure that your bots.

- Respond in a reasonable amount of time (say 250 ms)
- Will not damage my host machine

Comment: @Moogie I have decided to release this

Comment: In the local map, what does it show for tiles beyond the vision of the bots?

Comment: It shows the map. The only thing is that you can not see the bots at a larger distance. Your bots are provided with an actual map of the arena, but they may not where there stealthy opponents are hiding. @justhalf

Comment: @Moogie, I was wondering if you could write a python bot for me so i can test the stdin/stdout wrapper

Comment: So the map beyond the bots vision will just show as empty space, right?

Comment: @justhalf so you can see walls and ammunition beyond your bots vision, but you can not see other bots. The rational being that your bot has an excellent memory and is provided a map before the game.

Comment: Yes, by "can not see other bots", in place of other bots, it will be empty space ("O"), right?

Comment: @justhalf yes in palce of other bots The arena will show an empty space "O"

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala I am in the process of making a bot that uses the wrapper. It is java based, however it communicates via the stdin/out wrapper. So far there has been no issues in the controller or the wrapper.

Comment: nothing to see, i mis-understood the spec

Comment: Ok let me know when you make it, I would love to see a competition between two different bots

Comment: @Moogie ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala been busy :P work and getting ready to move house. I will try to get it up and running tonight if i get some free time. However i think there is a minor change that may be necessary for the stdin/out wrapper as some information is not available: the current game frame count. If the bot is in the slow area of the map then then a bot's internal frame count will get out of synch with the actual game frame count. I proposed that the interface be updated to include the current game frame so that all bots can be synchronised.

Comment: Ok, I can add that if you dwould like. let me know if you wish for me to push it tot the repo. @Moogie

Comment: sounds good to me

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala i have added a bot :) It does expect that the stdin/out interface sends the current frame as the first entry after the "FRAME" constant.

Comment: @Moogie how do i run it?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala i'll upload a 'moogie' branch to the git repo later, moving house today

Comment: @Moogie all right sounds good, good luck with the move!

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala moogie branch added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## NavPointBot, Java 8

[image]
Bot is white/blue

This bot nominates a leader from friendly bots each frame that will then assign nav points for each bot to navigate to.

Initally, all bots are on ammo depot finding duty, then two bots are assigned as guards with the remainder looking for ammo and then attacking the enemy flag.

I have found that the game is very dependant on the starting location of depots. As such i cannot really say that this bot is better than any others.

Run with `java NavPointBot`

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public final class NavPointBot implements Serializable 
{
    private static final int[][] offsets = new int[][]{{-1,0},{0,-1},{1,0},{0,1}};
    private static final List<int[]> navPointsBlue = Arrays.asList(new int[][]{{1,2},{2,1}});
    private static final List<int[]> navPointsRed = Arrays.asList(new int[][]{{63,62},{62,63}});
    transient private static int mapWidth=0;
    transient private static int mapHeight=0;
    transient private char[][] map;
    transient private char team;
    transient private int ammo;
    transient private int botsAlive;
    transient private int enemyFlagX;
    transient private int enemyFlagY;
    private int frameCount;
    private int botX;
    private int botY;
    private String id;
    private int navPointX;
    private int navPointY;

    transient static Object synchObject = new Object(); // used for file read/write synchronisation if multiple instances are run in the same VM

    final static class Data implements Serializable
    {
        int frameCount;
        boolean[][] diffusedMap = new boolean[mapWidth][mapHeight];
        Map<String,NavPointBot> teamMembers = new HashMap<>();
    }

    interface DistanceWeigher
    {
        double applyWeight(NavPointBot p1Bot, PathSegment p1);
    }

    static class PathSegment
    {
        public PathSegment(int tileX, int tileY, int fscore, int gscore, PathSegment parent, int direction, int targetX, int targetY)
        {
            super();
            this.tileX = tileX;
            this.tileY = tileY;
            this.fscore = fscore;
            this.gscore = gscore;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.direction = direction;
            this.targetX = targetX;
            this.targetY = targetY;
        }
        public PathSegment(PathSegment parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.targetX = parent.targetX;
            this.targetY = parent.targetY;
        }
        int tileX;
        int tileY;
        int fscore;
        int gscore;
        int direction;
        PathSegment parent; 
        int targetX;
        int targetY;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new NavPointBot(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    private NavPointBot(String id) throws Exception
    {
        this.id = id;
        System.err.println("NavPointBot ("+id+") STARTED");

        Data data;
        while(true)
        {
            String line=readLine(System.in);

            // decode initial frame
            if ("INIT".equals(line))
            {
                // read team membership
                team = readLine(System.in).charAt(0);

                // get the map
                line = readLine(System.in);

                List<char[]> mapLines = new ArrayList<>();
                while(!"TINI".equals(line))
                {
                    mapLines.add(line.toCharArray());
                    line = readLine(System.in);
                }
                map = mapLines.toArray(new char[][]{});
                mapHeight = map.length;
                mapWidth = map[0].length;

                out:
                for (int y = 0; y<mapHeight;y++)
                {
                    for (int x=0; x<mapWidth;x++)
                    {
                        if (map[y][x]==(team=='B'?'G':'F'))
                        {
                            enemyFlagX = x;
                            enemyFlagY = y;
                            break out;
                        }
                    }
                }
                data = readSharedData();
                data.diffusedMap=new boolean[mapWidth][mapHeight];
                writeSharedData(data);

            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("Unknown command received: "+line);
                return;
            }

            line = readLine(System.in);
            while (true)
            {
                // decode frame
                if ("FRAME".equals(line))
                {
                    frameCount = Integer.parseInt(readLine(System.in));
                    ammo = Integer.parseInt(readLine(System.in));
                    botsAlive = Integer.parseInt(readLine(System.in));
                    line = readLine(System.in);
                    String[] splits = line.split(",");
                    botX = Integer.parseInt(splits[0]);
                    botY = Integer.parseInt(splits[1]);

                    // get the map
                    line = readLine(System.in);

                    int row=0;
                    while(!"EMARF".equals(line))
                    {
                        map[row++] = line.toCharArray();
                        line = readLine(System.in);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.err.println("Unknown command received: "+line);
                    return;
                }


                data = readSharedData();

                // this bot is nomitated to be the leader for this frame
                if (data.frameCount<frameCount || (frameCount==0 && data.frameCount > 3))
                {
                    data.frameCount=frameCount;

                    List<NavPointBot> unassignedBots = new ArrayList<>(data.teamMembers.values());

                    // default nav points to be enemy flag location.
                    unassignedBots.forEach(t->{t.navPointY=enemyFlagY;t.navPointX=enemyFlagX;});

                    // after 700 frames assume dead lock so just storm the flag, otherwise...
                    if (frameCount<700)
                    {
                        // if the after the initial rush then we will assign guard(s) while we have enemies
                        if (frameCount>70 && botsAlive > data.teamMembers.size())
                        {
                            Map<NavPointBot, PathSegment> navPointDistances = assignBotShortestPaths(unassignedBots,team=='B'?navPointsBlue:navPointsRed,true, new DistanceWeigher() {

                                @Override
                                public double applyWeight( NavPointBot owner ,PathSegment target) {
                                    return target.gscore;
                                }
                            });
                            navPointDistances.keySet().forEach(s->{s.navPointX=navPointDistances.get(s).targetX;s.navPointY=navPointDistances.get(s).targetY;});
                        }


                        // the remaining bots will go to ammo depots with a preference to the middle ammo depots
                        List<int[]> ammoDepots = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int y = 0; y<mapHeight;y++)
                        {
                            for (int x=0; x<mapWidth;x++)
                            {
                                if (map[y][x]=='A')
                                {
                                    ammoDepots.add(new int[]{x,y});
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        System.err.println("ammoDepots: "+ammoDepots.size());
                        if (ammoDepots.size()>0)
                        {
                            Map<NavPointBot, PathSegment> ammoDistances = assignBotShortestPaths(unassignedBots,ammoDepots,true, new DistanceWeigher() {

                                @Override
                                public double applyWeight( NavPointBot owner ,PathSegment target) {
                                    return target.gscore + (Math.abs(target.targetX-mapWidth/2)+Math.abs(target.targetY-mapHeight/2)*10);
                                }
                            });


                            // assign ammo depot nav points to closest bots
                            ammoDistances.keySet().forEach(s->{s.navPointX=ammoDistances.get(s).targetX;s.navPointY=ammoDistances.get(s).targetY;});
                        }
                    }

                    System.err.println("FRAME: "+frameCount+" SET");
                    data.teamMembers.values().forEach(bot->System.err.println(bot.id+" nav point ("+bot.navPointX+","+bot.navPointY+")"));
                    System.err.println();
                }


                // check to see if enemies are in range, if so attack the closest
                List<int[]> enemies = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int y = 0; y<mapHeight;y++)
                {
                    for (int x=0; x<mapWidth;x++)
                    {
                        if (map[y][x]==(team=='B'?'R':'B'))
                        {
                            int attackDir = -1;
                            int distance = -1;
                            if (x==botX && Math.abs(y-botY) < 4) { distance =  Math.abs(y-botY); attackDir = botY-y<0?1:3;}
                            if (y==botY && Math.abs(x-botX) < 4) { distance =  Math.abs(x-botX); attackDir = botX-x<0?0:2;}
                            if (attackDir>-1)
                            {
                                enemies.add(new int[]{x,y,distance,attackDir});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                enemies.sort(new Comparator<int[]>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(int[] arg0, int[] arg1) {
                        return arg0[2]-arg1[2];
                    }
                });

                String action;

                // attack enemy if one within range...
                if (enemies.size()>0)
                {
                    action = "Throw,"+enemies.get(0)[3];
                }
                else
                {
                    // set action to move to navpoint
                    PathSegment pathSegment = pathFind(botX,botY,navPointX,navPointY,map,true);
                    action = "Move,"+pathSegment.direction;

                    // clear mines if within 5 spaces of enemy flag

                    if ((team=='B' && botX>=mapWidth-5 && botY>=mapHeight-5 ) ||
                        (team=='R' && botX<5 && botY<5 ))
                    {
                        if (!data.diffusedMap[pathSegment.parent.tileX][pathSegment.parent.tileY])
                        {
                            action = "Defuse,"+pathSegment.direction;
                            data.diffusedMap[pathSegment.parent.tileX][pathSegment.parent.tileY]=true;
                        }
                    }

                }

                writeSharedData(data);
                System.out.println(action);
                line = readLine(System.in);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * assigns bots to paths to the given points based on distance to the points with weights adjusted by the given weigher implementation 
     */
    private Map<NavPointBot, PathSegment> assignBotShortestPaths(List<NavPointBot> bots, List<int[]> points, boolean exact, DistanceWeigher weigher) {

        Map<Integer,List<PathSegment>> pathMap = new HashMap<>();
        final Map<PathSegment,NavPointBot> pathOwnerMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (NavPointBot bot : bots)
        {
            for(int[] navPoint: points)
            {
                List<PathSegment> navPointPaths = pathMap.get((navPoint[0]<<8)+navPoint[1]);
                if (navPointPaths == null)
                {
                    navPointPaths = new ArrayList<>();
                    pathMap.put((navPoint[0]<<8)+navPoint[1],navPointPaths);
                }
                PathSegment path = pathFind(bot.botX,bot.botY,navPoint[0],navPoint[1],map,exact);
                pathOwnerMap.put(path, bot);
                navPointPaths.add(path);
            }
        }


        // assign bot nav point based on shortest distance
        Map<NavPointBot, PathSegment> results = new HashMap<>();
        for (int[] navPoint: points )
        {
            List<PathSegment> navPointPaths = pathMap.get((navPoint[0]<<8)+navPoint[1]);

            if (navPointPaths !=null)
            {
                Collections.sort(navPointPaths, new Comparator<PathSegment>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(PathSegment p1, PathSegment p2) {

                        NavPointBot p1Bot = pathOwnerMap.get(p1);
                        NavPointBot p2Bot = pathOwnerMap.get(p2);
                        double val = weigher.applyWeight(p1Bot, p1) - weigher.applyWeight(p2Bot, p2);
                        if (val == 0)
                        {

                            return p1Bot.id.compareTo(p2Bot.id);
                        }
                        return val<0?-1:1;
                    }
                });

                for (PathSegment shortestPath : navPointPaths)
                {
                    NavPointBot bot = pathOwnerMap.get(shortestPath);

                    if (!results.containsKey(bot) )
                    {
                        results.put(bot,shortestPath);
                        bots.remove(bot);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * reads in the previous bot's view of teammates aka shared data
     */
    private Data readSharedData() throws Exception
    {
        synchronized(synchObject)
        {
            File dataFile = new File(this.getClass().getName()+"_"+team);

            Data data;
            if (dataFile.exists())
            {
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(dataFile);
                try {
                    java.nio.channels.FileLock lock = in.getChannel().lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, true);
                    try {
                        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                        data = (Data) ois.readObject();
                    } catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.err.println(id+": CORRUPT shared Data... re-initialising");
                        data = new Data();
                    }
                    finally {
                        lock.release();
                    }
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println(id+": No shared shared Data exists... initialising");
                data = new Data();
            }

            //purge any dead teammates...
            for (NavPointBot bot : new ArrayList<>(data.teamMembers.values()))
            {
                if (bot.frameCount < frameCount-3 || bot.frameCount > frameCount+3)
                {
                    data.teamMembers.remove(bot.id);
                }
            }

            // update our local goals to reflect those in the shared data
            NavPointBot dataBot = data.teamMembers.get(id);
            if (dataBot !=null)
            {
                this.navPointX=dataBot.navPointX;
                this.navPointY=dataBot.navPointY;
            }

            // ensure that we are a team member
            data.teamMembers.put(id, this);

            return data;
        }
    }

    private void writeSharedData(Data data) throws Exception
    {
        synchronized(synchObject)
        {
            File dataFile = new File(this.getClass().getName()+"_"+team);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);

            try {
                java.nio.channels.FileLock lock = out.getChannel().lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, false);
                try {
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
                    oos.writeObject(data);
                    oos.flush();
                } finally {
                    lock.release();
                }
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * return the direction to move to travel for the shortest route to the desired target location
     */
    private PathSegment pathFind(int startX, int startY, int targetX,int targetY,char[][] map,boolean exact)
    {
        // A*
        if (startX==targetX && startY==targetY)
        {
            return new PathSegment(targetX,targetY,0, 0,null,4,targetX,targetY);//PathSegment.DEFAULT;
        }
        else
        {
            int[][] tileIsClosed = new int[mapWidth][mapHeight];

            // find an open space in the general vicinity if exact match not required
            if (!exact)
            {
                out:
                for (int y=-1;y<=1;y++)
                {
                    for (int x=-1;x<=1;x++)
                    {
                        if (startX == targetX+x && startY==targetY+y)
                        {
                            return new PathSegment(targetX,targetY,0, 0,null,4,targetX,targetY);//PathSegment.DEFAULT;
                        }
                        else if (targetY+y>=0 && targetY+y<mapHeight && targetX+x>=0 && targetX+x < mapWidth && map[targetY+y][targetX+x]=='O')
                        {
                            targetX+=x;
                            targetY+=y;
                            break out;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            PathSegment curSegment = new PathSegment(targetX,targetY,1,1,null,4,targetX,targetY);
            PathSegment newSegment;
            Set<PathSegment> openList = new HashSet<PathSegment>();
            openList.add(curSegment);

            do
            {
                if (openList.isEmpty())
                {
                    break;
                }
              PathSegment currentBestScoringSegment = openList.iterator().next();
              //  Look for the lowest F cost square on the open list
              for (PathSegment segment : openList)
              {
                if (segment.fscore<currentBestScoringSegment.fscore)
                {
                  currentBestScoringSegment = segment;
                }
              }
              curSegment = currentBestScoringSegment;

              // found path
              if (startX==curSegment.tileX && startY==curSegment.tileY)
              {
                break;
              }

              // if not in closed list
              if (tileIsClosed[curSegment.tileX][curSegment.tileY]==0)
              {
                    // Switch it to the closed list.
                    tileIsClosed[curSegment.tileX][curSegment.tileY]=1;
                    // remove from openlist
                    openList.remove(curSegment);


                    // add neigbours to the open list if necessary
                    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
                    {

                        int surroundingCurrentTileX=curSegment.tileX+offsets[i][0];
                        int surroundingCurrentTileY=curSegment.tileY+offsets[i][1];
                        if (surroundingCurrentTileX>=0 && surroundingCurrentTileX<mapWidth &&
                            surroundingCurrentTileY>=0 && surroundingCurrentTileY<mapHeight )
                        {
                            newSegment = new PathSegment( curSegment);
                            newSegment.tileX = surroundingCurrentTileX;
                            newSegment.tileY = surroundingCurrentTileY;
                            newSegment.direction = i;

                            switch(map[surroundingCurrentTileY][surroundingCurrentTileX])
                            {
                                case 'W':
                                case 'F':
                                case 'G':
                                    continue;
                            }

                          int surroundingCurrentGscore=curSegment.gscore+1 + ((surroundingCurrentTileX!=startX && surroundingCurrentTileY!=startY && map[surroundingCurrentTileY][surroundingCurrentTileX]==team)?20:0);//+map[surroundingCurrentTileY][surroundingCurrentTileX]!='O'?100:0;
                          newSegment.gscore=surroundingCurrentGscore;
                          newSegment.fscore=surroundingCurrentGscore+Math.abs( surroundingCurrentTileX-startX)+Math.abs( surroundingCurrentTileY-startY);
                          openList.add(newSegment);
                        }
                    }
              }
              else
              {
                  // remove from openlist
                  openList.remove(curSegment);    
              }
            } while(true);

            return curSegment;
        }
     }

    /**
     * Reads a line of text from the input stream. Blocks until a new line character is read.
     * NOTE: This method should be used in favor of BufferedReader.readLine(...) as BufferedReader buffers data before performing
     * text line tokenization. This means that BufferedReader.readLine() will block until many game frames have been received. 
     * @param in a InputStream, nominally System.in
     * @return a line of text or null if end of stream.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static String readLine(InputStream in) throws IOException
    {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       int readByte = in.read();
       while (readByte>-1 && readByte!= '\n')
       {
          sb.append((char) readByte);
          readByte = in.read();
       }
       return readByte==-1?null:sb.toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: beautiful animation, just out of curiosity what is the approximate win percentage of my bot?

Comment: I have not performed any real statistics but i would hazard 60% my bot vs 40% your bot? but really depends on the placement of ammo

Comment: Ok, gg on the win!

Comment: should I had more ammo, or should I configure the ammo to spawn equally?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala i think it is what it is, too late to change the behaviour now. Use it as a learning experience for the next question asked :)

Comment: ok that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

## Optimised Pathfinder JAVA

Thanks to @Moogie for helping me optimise my messy floodfill pathfinding. Here is the source for the bot. This guy knows how important it is to defend his flag. He alocates three defenders and two attackers. The defenders hang back and defend/gather ammo, the two attackers take (a fairly straight) path to the flag (and collect the ammo at the middle). He shoots anyone he sees, and should be fierce competition. The defenders place mines around the flag and camp until there is no opposition left so they can go and kick the can.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 * todo fight
 */
package botctf;

import botctf.Move.MoveType;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 * @author rohan
 */
public class PathFinderOptimised extends Bot {
    private static final int[][] offsets = new int[][]{{0,-1},{1,0},{0,1},{-1,0}};
    public static boolean shouldCampingTroll = true;
    private int moveCounter = -1;//dont ask
    public boolean defend;

    public PathFinderOptimised(int inX, int inY, int inTeam) {

        super(inX, inY, inTeam);
        //System.out.println("Start");
        //floodFillMap(getX(), getY());
        //System.out.println("Finish");
        defend=inX%2==0;
    }
    public static int[][] navigationMap;

    boolean upMine = false;
    boolean sideMine = false;

        int[][] myMap;

    @Override
    public Move move() {
                moveCounter++;
        myMap=getMap();
        int targetX, targetY;
        int enemyTeam=team==redTeam?blueTeam:redTeam;
        ArrayList<Coord> enemyCoordinates=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<65;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<65;j++){
                if(map[i][j]==enemyTeam){
                    enemyCoordinates.add(new Coord(i,j));
                }
            }
        }
        for(Coord enemy:enemyCoordinates){
            int enemyX=enemy.x;
            int enemyY=enemy.y;
         int dX= enemy.x-this.x;
            int dY= enemy.y-this.y;
            //System.out.println(dX+"|"+dY);
            if((dX==0||dY==0)){

                if(Arena.getAmmo()[this.team]>0){

                    if(dX>0&&dX<5){
                    return new Move(0,MoveType.Throw);
                }
                if(dX<0&&dX>-5){
                    return new Move(2,MoveType.Throw);
                }
                if (dY>0&&dY<5){
                    return new Move(1, MoveType.Throw);
                }
                if(dY<0&&dY>-5){
                    return new Move(3,MoveType.Throw);
                }
            }
        }
        }
        if(myMap[x+1][y]==ammo){
            return new Move(0,MoveType.Move);
        }
                if(myMap[x-1][y]==ammo){
            return new Move(2,MoveType.Move);
        }
                                if(myMap[x][y+1]==ammo){
            return new Move(1,MoveType.Move);
        }
                                                                if(myMap[x][y-1]==ammo){
            return new Move(3,MoveType.Move);
        }


int bestOption = 4;                                                             
        if (defend) {
if(Arena.getAliveBots()==1){
    defend=false;
}
            int bestAmmoX = -1;
            int bestAmmoY = -1;
            int bestAmmoDist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < 65; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 65; j++) {
                    if (myMap[i][j] == ammo) {
                        int path = pathFind(getX(),getY(),i,j,myMap);
                        if ((path & 0xFFFFFF) < bestAmmoDist) {
                            bestAmmoX = i;
                            bestAmmoY = j;
                            bestAmmoDist = (path & 0xFFFFFF);
                            bestOption = path >> 24;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (bestAmmoDist<15||Arena.getAmmo()[this.team]==0){
                targetX = bestAmmoX;
                targetY = bestAmmoY;
            } else {
                targetX = team == redTeam ? 62 : 2;
                targetY = team == redTeam ? 62 : 2;
            }
        } else {

            if(this.x>18&this.x<42&&this.y>16&&this.y<44&&myMap[33][33]==ammo){
                targetX=33;
                targetY=33;
            }else{
            if (this.team == redTeam) {
                targetX = 1;
                targetY = 1;
            } else {
                targetX = 63;
                targetY = 63;
            }
            }
        }
        if(upMine&&sideMine){
            if(targetX==2||targetX==62){
                if(targetY==2||targetY==62){
                    targetX+=targetX==2?3:-3;
                    targetY+=targetY==2?3:-3;
                }
            }
        }else if (targetX == getX() && targetY == getY()) {
            if (!upMine) {
                upMine = true;
                if (this.team == redTeam) {
                    return new Move(0, MoveType.Mine);
                } else {
                    return new Move(2, MoveType.Mine);
                }
            }else if(!sideMine){
                sideMine=true;      
                if (this.team == redTeam) {
                    return new Move(1, MoveType.Mine);
                } else {
                    return new Move(3, MoveType.Mine);
                }
            }   else {
                return new Move(5, MoveType.Move);
            }
        }

        bestOption = pathFind(getX(),getY(),targetX,targetY,myMap) >> 24;


MoveType m=MoveType.Move;
if(moveCounter%2==0){
    if(this.team==redTeam?x<25&&y<25:x>39&&y>39){
        m=MoveType.Defuse;
    }
}
//System.out.println(bestOption);
        return new Move(bestOption, m);
    }

    /**
     * returns a result that is the combination of movement direction and length of a path found from the given start position to the target
     * position. result is ((direction) << 24 + path_length)
     */
    private int pathFind(int startX, int startY, int targetX,int targetY,int[][] map)
    {
        class PathSegment
        {
            public PathSegment(int tileX, int tileY, int fscore, int gscore, PathSegment parent)
            {
                super();
                this.tileX = tileX;
                this.tileY = tileY;
                this.fscore = fscore;
                this.gscore = gscore;
                this.parent = parent;
            }
            public PathSegment(PathSegment parent)
            {
                this.parent = parent;
            }
            int tileX;
            int tileY;
            int fscore;
            int gscore;
            PathSegment parent; 
        }
        // A*
        if (startX==targetX && startY==targetY)
        {
            return 4;
        }
        else
        {
            int[][] tileIsClosed = new int[64][64];

            PathSegment curSegment = new PathSegment(targetX,targetY,1,1,null);
            PathSegment newSegment;
            Set<PathSegment> openList = new HashSet<PathSegment>();
            openList.add(curSegment);

            do
            {
                if (openList.isEmpty())
                {
                    break;
                }
              PathSegment currentBestScoringSegment = openList.iterator().next();
              //  Look for the lowest F cost square on the open list
              for (PathSegment segment : openList)
              {
                if (segment.fscore<currentBestScoringSegment.fscore)
                {
                  currentBestScoringSegment = segment;
                }
              }
              curSegment = currentBestScoringSegment;

              // found path
              if (startX==curSegment.tileX && startY==curSegment.tileY)
              {
                break;
              }

              // if not in closed list
              if (tileIsClosed[curSegment.tileX][curSegment.tileY]==0)
              {
                    // Switch it to the closed list.
                    tileIsClosed[curSegment.tileX][curSegment.tileY]=1;
                    // remove from openlist
                    openList.remove(curSegment);


                    // add neigbours to the open list if necessary
                    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
                    {
                        final int surroundingCurrentTileX=curSegment.tileX+offsets[i][0];
                        final int surroundingCurrentTileY=curSegment.tileY+offsets[i][1];
                        if (surroundingCurrentTileX>=0 && surroundingCurrentTileX<64 &&
                            surroundingCurrentTileY>=0 && surroundingCurrentTileY<64 )
                        {
                            newSegment = new PathSegment( curSegment);
                            newSegment.tileX = surroundingCurrentTileX;
                            newSegment.tileY = surroundingCurrentTileY;

                          if (map[surroundingCurrentTileX][surroundingCurrentTileY]=='W')
                          {
                              continue;
                          }

                          int surroundingCurrentGscore=curSegment.gscore+1;
                          newSegment.gscore=surroundingCurrentGscore;
                          newSegment.fscore=surroundingCurrentGscore+Math.abs( surroundingCurrentTileX-startX)+Math.abs( surroundingCurrentTileY-startY);
                          openList.add(newSegment);
                        }
                    }
              }
              else
              {
                  // remove from openlist
                  openList.remove(curSegment);    
              }
            } while(true);

            if (curSegment.parent.tileX-startX<0) return (2 << 24) | curSegment.gscore;
            else if (curSegment.parent.tileX-startX>0) return (0 << 24) | curSegment.gscore;
            else if (curSegment.parent.tileY-startY<0) return (3 << 24) | curSegment.gscore;
            else if (curSegment.parent.tileY-startY>0) return (1 << 24) | curSegment.gscore;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Path finding failed");
     }
}
```